# Plotting multi line plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a multi line plot with matplot lib. I have a csv with the following data. I'd like to make one plot with the x axis being epoch and the y axis being val_AUC. I'd like there to be 3 lines, each one representing a fold. How would I make this plot?

```
fold    epoch   val_loss    val_AUC
0   0   0.7 0.5
0   1   0.6 0.6
0   2   0.5 0.7
0   3   0.3 0.8
0   4   0.3 0.9
1   0   0.8 0.5
1   1   0.75    0.6
1   2   0.7 0.6
1   3   0.7 0.7
1   4   0.66    0.7
2   0   0.9 0.5
2   1   0.8 0.55
2   2   0.83    0.55
2   3   0.82    0.66
2   4   0.6 0.66
```

I know I can list each set of datapoints as a list but I'm wondering if I can call it from the csv and separate it by fold.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Data points of line 1
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
# Data points of line 2
x2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
# Data points of line 3
x3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y3 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
# Plotting all lines with specifying labels
plt.plot(x1, y1, label='Line 1')
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='Line 2')
plt.plot(x3, y3, label='Line 3')
# Adding legend, x and y labels, and titles for the lines
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Plotting Multiple Lines')
# Displaying the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Read the file with pandas (`import pandas as pd`), `df = pd.read_csv(file)`, and plot with seaborn (`import seaborn as sns`): `ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='epoch', y='val_AUC', hue='fold', legend='full')` [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic7N9.png). Seaborn is a high-level API for matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let's say I make the same plot for val_loss as ax2, how can I save both images side by side into one image file?

Comment: Melt the dataframe to a long form with `dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['fold', 'epoch'], var_name='Val')` and then plot a seaborn figure plot (the previous plot was an axes plot) with `g = sns.relplot(data=dfm, kind='line', x='epoch', y='value', col='Val', hue='fold', legend='full')` [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Gai.png)

Comment: Otherwise: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5), tight_layout=True)`, 
`sns.lineplot(data=df, x='epoch', y='val_AUC', hue='fold', legend='full', ax=ax1)`, 
`sns.lineplot(data=df, x='epoch', y='val_loss', hue='fold', legend='full', ax=ax2)`